# Cocos2d-android detecting bounding box of sprite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-android

Is it possible to detect collisions with certain parts of a sprite's bounding box? 
For example if a sprite jumps and landed into a platform, the bottom part of the sprite bounding box's and the top part of the platform bounding box's collision will be detected.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I have a helper library that has lots of little functions including something like:

```
CCRect CHelperMethods::InsetRect(const CCRect rectToInset, const float insetValueX, const float insetValueY) {
return CCRectMake(rectToInset.origin.x + insetValueY, rectToInset.origin.y + insetValueY, rectToInset.size.width - insetValueX * 2, rectToInset.size.height - insetValueY * 2);
}
```

Then, for example with a sprite that has landed, it would have a State variable, and I would say (psuedo code)

```
if(sprite.getState() == constStateLanded) {
    CheckCollisionForBox( CHelperMethods::InsetRect(sprite->boundingBox(), yourXOffset, yourYOffset));
}
```

HTH, as you tagged Android and ipHone I didn't know whether you wanted Obj-C or C++ :)

Comment: I tagged Android only and java for the language but thanks for your help! I'll try to use your suggestion. :)

Comment: Ah, I guess the other edit added the tags :). SAme thing applies in Java, though